# SUMIF or VLOOKUP for comma-joined / array

Tags: google-spreadsheets

[image: pic]

See toy example (Google Spreadsheets). Given column `D`, what formula do I need to enter in column `E` so that it gets the sum of the comma-separated list of values present in A? You can assume all items are present in A.

I know `SPLIT` can turn D into an array, but unsure how to use that and if I should `VLOOKUP` each item in the resulting array against columns A and B, or use `SUMIF`, or something else entirely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Formula in `E4`

Will calculate for all rows in `D4:D`

```
=BYROW(TOCOL(D4:D, 1), LAMBDA(_row,
   ARRAYFORMULA(
     SUM(
       VLOOKUP(
         SPLIT(_row, ","),
         A:B, 2, 0)))))
```

## Explanation

1. TOCOL returns an array containing the non-blank rows  from `D4:D`
2. BYROW passes each row of that array, one-by-one, into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row in the variable `_row`
3. LAMBDA's formula:

   1. SPLIT separates `_row`  into an array.
   2. VLOOKUP matches each each array member against the values in column `A` and returns the values in the same row of column `B`
   3. The array of values returned by VLOOKUP is then totalled using SUM.